# Unable to view remotely mounted filesystem in bash

Tags: command-line, bash, mount

I have a remotely mounted filesystem in addition to my local hard drives. I am using Ubuntu on Windows from the Microsoft store. Through DOS I can see all of my hard drives (C, D, E - which are the local hard drives, and Z which is the remote filesystem) and can navigate to and edit files in Z. Using the mount command in bash I only see C,D,E, and cannot navigate to it. Is there a different command I need to use or are there some permission that Ubuntu is missing in order to access it?

Thanks.